# Energy Balance Equation from a steam turbine

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's say a steam turbine produces Wt. If the energy of the steam flow entering the turbine is equal to E3, and the energy of the steam flow leaving the turbine is E4, and there is an energy loss of dEf, there is also an energy loss of dq.

Are dEf and dq internal energy from the system?
Are they necessary for energy balance equation?

Comment: I assume the energy loss dq is heat. But what is the energy loss dEf?

Comment: I have an answer for you but I can't complete it unless you tell me what the dEf loss term means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are dEf and dq internal energy from the system? Are they necessary for
> energy balance equation?

The short answer is all forms of energy entering and exiting the turbine need to be accounted for in the steady flow energy balance equation. I'm assuming the $dq$ loss term refers to heat loss from the turbine. Heat loss is not internal energy, but it reduces the energy available for performing turbine work.  I don't know what your $dE_f$ loss term is. But if it is some form of energy that is not available to produce turbine work, that energy must be accounted for in the energy balance equation. Given the suffix $f$ perhaps it relates to flow work?

> Sorry i didn't point out that dEf is energy loss due to friction. Does
> that mean dEf = Qin also?

Not necessarily. You can have an adiabatic ($Q=0$) turbine with friction losses (an irreversible turbine). The friction loss results in a higher exiting energy (a higher $E_4$) leaving less energy to perform turbine work. If the friction loss is not in $Q$ term, the energy balance becomes where $W_T$ is the turbine work:

$$W_{T}= E_{3}-E_{4}-dQ-dE_{f}$$

The Addendum below is given to you to help you understand the energy balance equation and how it relates to turbine work.

Hope it helps.

ADDENDUM:

Fig 1 below shows a generic open system and the steady flow equation governing the control volume. It accounts for shaft work, heat gain/loss, changes in kinetic and potential energy of the flow, changes in internal energy (contained in the enthalpy $h$ term), and flow work $pv$ required to move the fluid into and out of the turbine (also contained in the $h$ term).

In terms of your variables where $\dot W_{out}$ is the steam turbine output,

$$E_{3}= \dot m_{i}\biggr(u_{i}+p_{i}v_{i} +\frac{V_{i}^2}{2}+gZ_{i}\biggl)$$

$$E_{4}= \dot m_{i}\biggr(u_{e}+p_{e}v_{e} +\frac{V_{e}^2}{2}+gZ_{e}\biggl)$$

If by $dq$ you mean heat loss by the turbine, then

$$dq=\dot Q_{in}$$

where $\dot Q_{in}$ is in this case negative (leaving the control volume).

I don't know what you mean by the $dE_f$ loss term.

In most cases the changes in kinetic and potential energy of the flow entering and exiting the steam turbine are considered negligible. Also, if the steam turbine is adiabatic, then the heat loss term is zero. Thus for such an adiabatic turbine, Fig 1 is simplified to be Fig 2. Note that in the equations of Fig 2, the enthalpy term, $h$, incorporates the internal energy, $u$, and the pressure volume product, $pv$, of the flow, i.e, $h=u+pv$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry i didn't point out that dEf is energy loss due to friction. Does that mean dEf = Qin also?

Comment: Not necessarily. See update to my answer in response to your comment.